# Is it possible to transfer a file in separate bursts?

Tags: windows, usb, backup

I have a USB device, a Kindle, that is suffering a disabling bug. It can be fixed with a firmware update. Unfortunately, one of the symptoms of this bug is that the device can only be mounted for 15 seconds at a time, which is long enough to transfer across the 180 MB firmware update. I can only get, at most, 20% of it across at a time.

The only solution I can imagine is to transfer parts of the file in separate bursts. That is, start from byte 1 and transfer as much as possible until the device disconnects itself, and then when it can be reconnected, begin transferring again from where it left off.

Is there any way this is remotely possible?

Comment: So far as I know, the mass-storage interface doesn't provide for resumption of interrupted file transfer and the original Kindle doesn't provide any way to reassemble multiple fragments into a single file. If you have a Kindle Fire it may be possible - I suggest you specify your exact model.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I have a Kindle Paperwhite 1st gen. Regardless of model there is no way to make it do anything but behave as a USB hard drive: the entire reason I'm trying to get a firmware update on there is so that I can get it to boot.

Answer (score 0):

The [USB mass-storage interface](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/Mass_Storage_Specification_Overview_v1.4_2-19-2010.pdf) doesn't provide for resumption of interrupted file transfer across drive disconnections.